# bootstrap tabs doesn't work with different class name

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap works fine in my js if I have

```
$('.tabs').tabs();
```

But if I change that to something like

```
$('.usertabs').tabs();
```

and also change the corresponding ul it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with bootstrap-tabs? I'm using the latest bootstrap v1.4.0

```
<ul class="usertabs" data-tabs="tabs" >
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.usertabs').tabs('.usertabs li > a');
```

should work assuming your code looks something like

```
<ul class="usertabs" data-tabs="tabs" >
<li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#menu1">menu1</a></li>
<li><a href="#menu2">menu2</a></li>
<li><a href="#menu3">menu3</a></li>
</ul>
```

..the reason it works is if you look at bootstrap-tabs.js v1.4.0 `line 70` you'll see that the `$.fn.tabs` plugin/function takes in a selector as its parameter.

Btw, i think the `data-tabs="tabs"` is unnecessary at this point.