# Twitter Bootstrap pop-over not loading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

What am i doing wrong here?

I tried it in a larger project and couldnt get it to work either

see my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/keithmancuso/24RQM/

**UPDATE:** ok so i got it working if i manually add $(".pop").popover(); but do i have to initalize them like that?

I think the answer is yes... you do have the initialize them in your own code to get it to work... the easiest way i've found to do this is just add

```
$(function() {
    $('a[rel="popover"]').popover();
});
```

Comment: Hey Keith, your jsfiddle was blank when i looked at it. Probably should either add code to it, or just remove it.

Comment: As far as I know you indeed need to initialize the popovers like that. Bootstrap does not want to scan the entire dom (too slow) to do that automatically. (Quote from the bootstrap site: "For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt in. If you would like to use them just specify a the selector option. ")

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Was looking for a javascript-less version of the bootstrap popup but it doesn't seem possible. If you look at the page source of http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popover
at line 709-718 you will see that the example does something similar:

Heres a simplified version that works for me

```
<a href="#" class="btn danger" 
            rel="popover" 
            data-original-title="title" 
            data-content="content">popover</a>
<script>
  $("a[rel=popover]").popover();
</script>
```

**Edit:** for recent versions of twitter boostrap (right now 2.2.1) you might run into a problem where when you click on a popover link, you are taken to the top of the page. 
This answer might be beneficial too https://stackoverflow.com/a/13759775/341692 . Basically your js should now be

```
<script>
$("a[rel=popover]")
    .popover()
    .click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });​
</script>
```

Comment: He's right you need to call it like above w/ JS. Kind of strange cause all the other one I could just call by using the proper markup.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, i answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8598501/923817) concerning how to use selectors a with the bootstrap `tabs()` function. I bet `popover()` is similar.